# How to send two float in one package OSC

Tags: ios, objective-c, osc

i need to send in one package two float numbers. I use CocoaOSC project https://github.com/danieldickison/CocoaOSC

how i call function to send:

```
[delegate sendPacket:@"/ShotHappends" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f %.3f", myXRound, myYRound] type:2];
```

my function

```
- (void)sendPacket:(NSString*)address value:(NSString*)sendValue type:(int)type
{
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    remoteHost = [defaults stringForKey:@"host"];
    remotePort = [defaults stringForKey:@"port"];

    NSLog(@"Value: %@", sendValue);

    OSCMutableMessage *message = [[OSCMutableMessage alloc] init];
    message.address = address;

    sendType = type;

    switch (sendType)
    {
        case 0: [message addString:sendValue]; break;
        case 1: [message addInt:[sendValue intValue]]; break;
        case 2: [message addFloat:[sendValue floatValue]]; break;
        case 3: [message addBlob:[sendValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; break;
        case 4: [message addTimeTag:[NSDate date]]; break;
        case 5: [message addBool:YES]; break;
        case 6: [message addBool:NO]; break;
        case 7: [message addImpulse]; break;
        case 8: [message addNull]; break;
    }

    [connection sendPacket:message toHost:remoteHost port:[remotePort intValue]];
}
```

so as you see i create a string and say in my function what is in these string, if i say that string @"0,22 0,45" is float my server will get only first number, so how can i send two floats to my server? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, or even read the API, but I would imagine you would have to create a version of your method that accepts arrays of type/values:

```
- (void)sendPacket:(NSString*)address
            values:(NSArray*)values
             types:(NSArray*)types
{
    NSAssert([values count] == [types count], @"Values/types array are different sizes!");

    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    remoteHost = [defaults stringForKey:@"host"];
    remotePort = [defaults stringForKey:@"port"];

    OSCMutableMessage *message = [[OSCMutableMessage alloc] init];
    message.address = address;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [values count]; i++)
    {
        int sendType = [[types objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        id sendValue = [values objectAtIndex:i];

        switch (sendType)
        {
            case 0: [message addString:sendValue]; break;
            case 1: [message addInt:[sendValue intValue]]; break;
            case 2: [message addFloat:[sendValue floatValue]]; break;
            case 3: [message addBlob:[sendValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; break;
            case 4: [message addTimeTag:[NSDate date]]; break;
            case 5: [message addBool:YES]; break;
            case 6: [message addBool:NO]; break;
            case 7: [message addImpulse]; break;
            case 8: [message addNull]; break;
        }
    }

    [connection sendPacket:message toHost:remoteHost port:[remotePort intValue]];
}
```

Note: as you are passing the types (`int`) in an Objective-C collection class, they must be wrapped in `NSNumber` objects:

```
[delegate sendPacket:@"/ShotHappends"
              values:@[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", myXRound],
                       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", myYRound]
                      ]
               types:@[ @(2), @(2) ]
];
```

Note 2: An improvement to your method would be to pass strings as `NSString`, numbers/bools as `NSNumber` and data as `NSData` rather than using `NSString` all the time.  Up to you, though.